# Why do mouse events get promoted beside Touch events?

Tags: .net, wpf, touch, multi-touch, pixelsense

I would like to know please, how to prevent WPF promoting mouse events when the source of the event is a touch ?

I read the article of JoshB [here](http://nui.joshland.org/2010/04/why-wont-wpf-controls-work-with-touch.html) but, the mouse events keep getting triggered, although I did `e.Handled = true;`

Here is what JoshB says:

*The touch event flow with no manipulations. The touch events are unhandled, so WPF promotes the event to the mouse equivalent*

So, I tried in my code to mark the event as handled, but WPF still promotes mouse events once I touch the `_touchSurface` which is `InkSurface`

Here is my code: ( I am not using Microsoft Surface SDK )

```
_touchSurface.IsManipulationEnabled = true;
_touchSurface.TouchDown += new EventHandler<TouchEventArgs>(touchDown);
_touchSurface.TouchMove += new EventHandler<TouchEventArgs>(touchMove);
_touchSurface.TouchEnter += new EventHandler<TouchEventArgs>(touchEnter);
_touchSurface.TouchLeave += new EventHandler<TouchEventArgs>(touchLeave);

_touchSurface.ManipulationDelta += new EventHandler<ManipulationDeltaEventArgs>(ManipulationDelta);
_touchSurface.ManipulationStarting += new EventHandler<ManipulationStartingEventArgs>(ManipulationStarting);
_touchSurface.ManipulationCompleted += new EventHandler<ManipulationCompletedEventArgs>(ManipulationCompleted);


void touchDown(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
{
e.Handled = true;
}
void touchMove(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
{
e.Handled = true;
}
void touchLeave(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
{
e.Handled = true;
}


void ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
}

void ManipulationStarting(object sender, ManipulationStartingEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
}
void ManipulationCompleted(object sender, ManipulationCompletedEventArgs e)
{
   e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried PreviewTouchDown -Up, etc.?

Comment: Yes, I tried PreviewTouchDown& PreviewTouchMove, but WPF keep promoting mouse events too ..

Comment: did you found a solution ? ( if yes->post it ?)

Answer (score 1):

If you **don't** want mouse events to get promoted, then you **don't** need to handle `TouchDown` and set `e.Handled = true`. Then the manipulation code will step in and you won't get mouse events.

Answer (score 0):

Samir: I had just this same issue too.  Have you tried deriving a class from that UIElement based component and override the Mouse and Touch events(rather than setting event handlers )?

https://github.com/100kph/TouchMousePromotion has an example stub